# How can the windows phone use the .pls format?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can the windows phone use the .pls format?

I have search the answer on the internet already, but I didn't found it. If somebody know it please write me an something.
I read at here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=vs.92).aspx that the WP7 doesn't supported the .pls format, but in this situation How can I use it?
Where Do I have to start?

Answer (score 1):

A Pls file isn't a media codec, it's a play list file, so it wouldn't be listed in the list you've linked to.  But no it doesn't support a Pls play list, see the play lists section in [Supported Media Codecs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

If you need to support the pls format you'll have to write support for it yourself.  A pls file is just a text, so you should be able to parse it easily.  See the [.Pls Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_%28file_format%29) page.